# is it possible to have InterProcess communication in Java?

Tags: jvm, ipc

I have two Java Programs each running in its own JVM instance ? Can they communicate with each other using any IPC technique like Shared Memory or Pipes ? Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes; [D-BUS](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/) and [Pipes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html) are both easy to use, and cross-platform. D-BUS is useful for general message-passing IPC, and pipes for sending bulk data.

You can also open a TCP or UDP socket on localhost, if you need to support multiple clients connecting to a central server.

I also found an [implementation of UNIX sockets in Java](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/projects/java/), though it requires the JNI.

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/rmi/index.jsp

Java Remote Method Invocation (Java RMI) enables the programmer to create distributed Java technology-based to Java technology-based applications, in which the methods of remote Java objects can be invoked from other Java virtual machines*, possibly on different hosts. RMI uses object serialization to marshal and unmarshal parameters and does not truncate types, supporting true object-oriented polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Have a look at RMI or a Shared Memory concept like [Java Spaces](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/tools/JavaSpaces/).

Answer (score 1):

Use MemoryMappedByteBuffer in Java NIO for sharing memory between processes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly new initiative for language-agnostic IPC of columnar (i.e. array-based) data from Apache called [Plasma](http://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/08/08/plasma-in-memory-object-store/).

As of yet (Sept '17) there are no JVM bindings, but as the project is backed by the likes of Spark, I think it won't be long before we see an implementation.

My understanding however is that there is not a general IPC system, as it is geared toward sharing arrays of primitives like `double`,`long`, for scientific computing, rather than classes/objects; though I could be wrong here.
On the plus side, it's also language-agnostic, so you could use it to communicate with another (non-JVM) runtime. However, the OP did ask for Java IPC so this could be irrelevant.